# How to fully import an .fbx texture to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, fbx

I've imported my assets into the unity editor and extracted all of their textures, some of my models were imported without their full texture, specific parts were grayed out as though i didn't color them.
I would like to know how to import the full texture.

Important to mention I did not create these models, just colored them.

[Here is a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zUORKjHN0Taa8LatPnlUavb_lK7LtfSk) to images of the model and the model itself if you want to try and solve it.

Comment: I suffered similar problem. This is my Question and self answer posting. [how to fully import an fbx texture to unity](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109532/how-can-i-export-cycles-materials-to-unity-3d-with-correct-uv) My solution was that you must bake each textures separately. And you must add materials in unity with correct number. Here is an example image. thank you. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUV8T.png)

Comment: @MJStudio I could not find the option to add more than one material, where is it in the inspector? and how did you get 3 different textures from a single .fbx file?

Answer (score 0):

in Unity click on the model and expand it to see its contents. then select your materials and hit right click then click extract. select a folder to extract the materials to. once you have done this, you can edit the materials individually. Unity does its best to figure out the material of the import, but its not always accurate. now that you have your materials extracted you can import any textures your using and assign them them to the proper material. this should get your model properly rendered.

Comment: When I extract i get only one material, there is not way to change it.

You might have not understood my problem, only part of the texture got imported and the other part got gray, the part that did get imported is alright.

Comment: well it looks like theres not much light in your unity scene.... can you post a screenshot of the object hiearchy?

Comment: I changed the picture to one with more light and added a picture of the hierachy.
I is defenetly not the problem though.

Comment: no its defiantely the model. should have more than one object in it, since its joined, it wont allow you to add materials to the seperate parts, did the download come with a texture file? it will be hard to make one without knowing the models normals.

Comment: it didn't come with a texture, that's why i drew it myself, is there a way to solve it anyway?